# Command to add "macuser" to "_www" group?

Tags: php, macos, file-permissions

What is the command to add "macuser" to the "_www" group on my MacBookAir?

I am working on a PHP project which generates files and folders as _www:_www and of course macuser is unable to do anything with them. (Unless I login as root).

If I am correct, adding "macuser" to "_www" will make this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a macuser -t user _www
```

Comment: I have just tried that and it doesn't appear to make any difference. NetBeans is still only opening the files as read-only.

Comment: @Lea Hayes: You can check to make sure the command worked by running `id macuser` and looking for _www in the group list it prints.  Assuming it's there, the next question is: are the permissions on the files set to allow group write access?

Comment: Yes _www appears in the list. I used `chmod -R 775 testsite` and it changed all permissions and became useable. Future directories which are created by PHP are not accessible as they do not assign g+w. Do you know how to sort that?

Comment: Use the SUID and SGID with chmod : `chmod -R 6775 testsite`. More on sticky bit in chmod man page

Comment: That didn't make any difference. A directory gets created as _www:_www with 755 when it needs to be 775 instead.

Comment: First, check `umask()` function, otherwise, two solutions for you. 1. Run your server has `macuser` and not `_www` or 2. use `chmod()` after each file creation and use `mkdir()` with mod agrgument.

Comment: For the purposes of development, is it possible to have the PHP script automatically chmod the directories and files that it creates? Continuously having to manually chmod each time is consuming a lot of time. I am tempted to change the settings in apache so that it just uses macuser:staff...not sure if this is wise or not though. Thanks for persisting on this one - much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know any way to automatically chmod creates items. For apache server setting same uid and gid as current user doesn't matter until you are into development stage, but, into production stage (so without setting uid/gid), if you need to access files/directories through ftp (or ssh or…) without being login as root, you can't without using php chmod function. EDIT: I don't really understood, you succeed to change apache uid/gid?

Comment: At the moment I am working on the project on a development mac. When the website is live (I would assume) that apache would assign the package user (with cPanel) uid/gid for dynamically created files. This will not be a problem because that is the user account that would be used. But on my mac it is a whole different story. I will have a play with the php chmod function...didn't even realise there was one tbh. Thanks

Comment: This didn't solve my problem completely, but it has certainly made things a lot easier. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just change the Apache user to be you in in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Change

```
User _www
Group _www
```

to

```
User your_name
Group staff
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, I will try this out!